# Join fetch using weak reference in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

How to join fetch entity using weak reference in hibernate? For example, I have 2 entities (Parent and Child). How to add parentId property to Child entity to join fetch Parent and do not make this field a foreign key?

In the other words: can I made one to many relationship without foreign key? Is that possible?

Comment: I fail to understand what you're asking, and how that is related to weak references.

Comment: I have many different entities, which can be parents to some child entity. I want to have parentId property in my child entity, which will reference to one of this parent entities. I know, I can use additional map table, but is there any way to do it without foreign keys? I mean, joint fetch.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a foreign key which is primarily required for mappings?

Comment: it's quite strange, that fk is required. In raw SQL I can easily join all necessary tables but Hibernate require fk.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't require a foreign key. It requires an association between the entities. HQL is not SQL it uses entities and their associations. Not table and column names.

Comment: Yeah, but when I create association using OneToOne and JoinColumn annotations, Hibernate also creates FK.

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to create associations in a relational database. The foreign key is not necessary for Hibernate, it's a good thing to have it in the database to guarantee the coherence of your data.

Comment: So I'm interesting, if possible to make association without that FK? Can I just remove it after creating DB?

Comment: Yes, of course. Hibernate allows creating the database schema for you, but it's not required at all. Most of the time, you create your schema with SQL scripts, and map it to entities with Hibernate. As long as the tables and columns match, no problem for Hibernate. But why would you want to avoid a foreign key constraint? That's a good thing to have it.